# How to use \mathbb with this font?

Tags: fonts, sourcecode, math-fonts, eulervm, mathbb

I have been using the Garamond font for almost 10 years and now I decided to change, to try something new, and after having spent some hours in reading and looking for TeX Fonts, I came up with the decision that to me another great and good looking font is given by

```
\usepackage{newpxtext} 
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
```

Yet when I was going to compile a token-document, some warnings appeared. Nothing strange, just the fact that the following string was not recognized

```
m\in\mathbb{R} \qquad \mathbb{1}
```

The output document did contain all what I wrote except for the \mathbb part.

Now I ask: is there a way to fix this, to get \mathbb letters (as well as the "identity" operator, 1, in \mathbb)?

To give you an example, here is what Garamond font would output, VS those new fonts.

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Note 1, it's recommended to provide a full MWE.

Comment: @user202729 Uhm, in what sense? Shall I add the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a `\mathbb` alphabet, which `eulervm` doesn't provide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

\[
m\in\mathbb{R}\qquad\mathbb{1}
\]
Some text in between with math $m\in\mathbb{R}$ to see
whether $a+b$ combines well.
\[
\int_{\Omega} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}
\frac{\ell \vec{v}}{r^2}\,d\hat{x}\,\nabla\phi+\psi\Theta\,\partial f
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure I'd use Times together with Euler, however.

Comment: Do you have any advice about what font/package to use? Euler sounded good to me, but if you have any suggestion I will take them as gold!

Comment: @Henry I'd go with `newtxmath`. But it's a question of personal taste.