# stix2.sty not found? Stix2 mathbb problem

Tags: packages, installing, compilation-error, sourcecode, mathbb

I have recently asked a question about changing fonts in my LaTeX document ([HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650843/how-to-use-mathbb-with-this-font#650847)) but when going to compile, it gave me errors.
Provided that I installed mathalpha, which I did not have, I have troubles in understanding how to install the stix2 package. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.8in, right=0.8in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha}

\newcommand\va{a}
\newcommand\vu{u}

\begin{document}

\[ m\in\mathbb{R} \qquad \mathbb{1} \qquad \int_{\Omega}\ \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}         
\dfrac{\ell \va*{v}}{r^2} \text{d}\vu*{x} \nabla \phi + \psi \Theta \partial f \]


\end{document}
```

This is the console output:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf stix2-mathbb

! I can't find file `stix2-mathbb'.
<*> ...ur; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input stix2-mathbb
                                              
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ur; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input stix2-mathbb
                                              
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: stix2-mathbb.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input stix2-                                       mathbb' failed to make stix2-mathbb.tfm.
./PROVE FONT.tex:22: Font U/stixtwobb/m/n/7.5=stix2-mathbb at 7.5pt not loadabl
e: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
               relax 
l.22 $$m\in\mathbb{R}
                  \qquad \mathbb{1} \qquad \int_{\Omega}\ \sum_{k = 1}^{...

?
```

I have no idea of what this all means, except for the line "I can't find file `stix2-mathbb'"

Thank you for any help.

I have to precise that all of this is cause to my need of the \mathbb characters.

**Add**

This is another part of the log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)     (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./PROVE FONT.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document     class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry    /geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek    /ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/stix.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
`newtxtext' v1.466, 2016/03/27 Text macros taking advantage of     TeX-Gyre Termes 
fonts (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes    /fontaxes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval    /xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval    /xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) 
Babel
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtlf.fd))
(/Users/Henry/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eulervm/eulervm.sty)
(/Users/Henry/Library/texmf/tex/latex/mathalpha/mathalpha.sty
`mathalpha' v1.143, 2021/11/18, a renaming of mathalfa (msharpe))
No file "PROVE FONT".aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls1stix.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stix.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/Users/Henry/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeur.fd)
(/Users/Henry/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeus.fd)
(/Users/Henry/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eulervm/uzeuex.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls1stixfrak.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls1stixbb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stixcal.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls1stixsf.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stixtt.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm stix2-mathbb
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1;     nonstopmode; input stix2-mathbb
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded     base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf stix2-mathbb


kpathsea: Running mktextfm stix2-mathbb
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1;     nonstopmode; input stix2-mathbb
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded     base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf stix2-mathbb

! I can't find file `stix2-mathbb'.
```

Comment: You had not provided an example, I fixed your fragment to be an example document. It runs without error in texlive, just on warning `Missing character: There is no � in font zeuex10!` Your fonts are incorrectly installed. Did you install stix2 and mathalpha "by hand" or via your tex system package manager?

Comment: You have not shown the relvant part of the log but you should see `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/stix2-type1/stix2-mathbb.enc` being logged  (with whatever full path your system uses)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Example? I wrote the code I wanted to compile... Anyway I installed only mathalpha by hand (moving the sty files in the ~Library etc...). I have no idea how to install stix2.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Going to add the other part of the log in the question

Comment: A fragment is not useful, especially if we have to guess how to complete the preamble and avoid errors from undefined commads and blank lines. See my edit, now everyone can run the same test and compare logs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added details (the whole log)

Comment: No you can not install a font package just by copying .sty you are missing the important parts such as the actual fonts, and the map files that tell tex what to do with them.  Undo that the use the Mactex? package manager  to install mathalpha

Comment: 2016, you could consider updating your tex system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am really a mess with all this things... Can you please provide me a fast (if possible, just to not annoy you too much) way to do things in a good way?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use TeXShop v 4.76, 2022...

Comment: If you had a current system you would just type `tlmgr install mathalpha`  and that would be it, but you can not use `tlmgr` on a 2016 system as tug do not keep "live" updates. Obviously in principle you can install all the type1 fonts, the tfm font metrics, the map files and the latex .sty and .fd files in the correct places. But to be honest I would not do that. Either use a 2016 system with 2016 packages, or (simpler) update to a current system if you want to use current packages.

Comment: texshop is just the editor, it is not involved here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was completely unaware... How can I update to a current system? Consider that I run TeX on a Macbook pro, with Os Big Sur. Cannot update further.

Comment: @Henry - Are you familiar with https://www.tug.org/mactex/?

Comment: @Mico If I am not wrong, I believe I used it before 2018

Comment: @Mico I believe it's time to use it back. But first, I need to format the whole computer (I have to do it). I smell like my problems will be solved after having installed MacTeX...

Comment: @Henry - Do also check if you can update your computer's operating system from MacOS 11 "Big Sur" to MacOS 12 "Monterey".